# Terminar ejecución de un setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una función de ticaje, en la que cuando se pulsa un botón empieza a contar el tiempo desde una fecha dada hasta la fecha actual. Dentro de esta función uso un interval para ir pintando el tiempo en horas , minutos y segundos en un div. El problema es  que cuando yo pulso el "Boton" para salir, el interval sigue ejecutandose y mostrandose en pantalla. Como opción puedo ocultar el div pero me gustaría saber como se puede parar la ejecución.

```
function estadoInicioFch(org,source){ 

const $switch = $('#switch-label');
var intervalID;


var parametros = {
    "org": org,
};


$.ajax({
    url: "php/Trbj/getPresente.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: parametros,
    success: function (data) {
        var objeto = $.parseJSON(data);
        var fecha = objeto.fch_tim;
        var presente = objeto.presente;
        var user_name = objeto.user_name;
        if(org==1){
            name_ticador="Presencia";
        }
        else{
            name_ticador="Produccion";
        }
        
        $('#bienVenido').text(user_name+" estas en  el ticador de " +name_ticador); // Modificar el contenido del div
        //Vengo de la web de trb.html
                if(presente==1){
                    if(source==1){ //Para comprobar si tengo que mover el botón por que acabo de entrar, o no lo muevo por que es un click y ya se mueve solo por css
                        $switch.prop('checked', true);
                    }
                    
                    var intervalID=comienzaIntervalo(fecha);
                    localStorage.setItem(interval, intervalID);
                    var interval = localStorage.getItem(interval);
                    $('#tiempo').show(); //oculto mediante id
                    
                }
                else{
                    alert("entrando");
                    detenerIntervalo(interval); //Aqui quiero detener el intervalo
                    if(source==1){
                        $switch.prop('checked',false);//Para comprobar si tengo que mover el botón por que acabo de entrar, o no lo muevo por que es un click y ya se mueve solo por css
                    }
                    
                    //$('#tiempo').hide(); //oculto mediante id
                    
                }
        }
});
```

}

```
function detenerIntervalo(intervalID) {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
}

function comienzaIntervalo(fecha){
    intervalID=setInterval(function() {
        tiempoTicado(fecha);
    }, 1000); 
    
}



function tiempoTicado(fecha){
    const myDatetime = fecha;
    const splitString = myDatetime.split(" ");//Se separa la cadena a partir del espacio entre la fecha y la hora
    const splitDate = splitString[0].split("/");//Se separan los elementos de la fecha
    const splitTime = splitString[1].split(":");//Se separan los elementos de la hora
    //Con los elementos separados, y para tener más orden y claridad, se puede asignar cada valor a variables cuyos nombres sean fáciles de identificar.
    //Enseguida, tendrás que restarle una unidad al valor del mes, esto debido a que el objeto Date de JavaScript trabaja con los meses de una manera similar a como lo hacen los arreglos y sus índices; es decir, empezando por el cero, lo cual quiere decir que, por ejemplo, el mes dado como 6, será interpretado como el séptimo. Asimismo, como el formato de la fecha es de cuatro dígitos, tendrás que completar la parte faltante. Esto puedes hacerlo concatenando el 20 con el valor de la variable del año.
    const day = splitDate[0]; //EL dia
    const month = splitDate[1] - 1;//El mes
    const year = `20${splitDate[2]}`;//El año
    const hours = splitTime[0];
    const minutes = splitTime[1];
    //Ya con todos los valores separados y formateados, puedes construir un objeto de fecha:
    const finalDatetime = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes);
    const realDatetime = new Date(); //La fecha y hora del sistema
    //Finalmente, solo quedará realizar la resta de forma directa y dividir el resultado, dado en milésimas de segundo, entre el producto de 60 por 1000, esto debido a que se requiere transformar las milésimas de segundo a segundos y estos a minutos. Además de ello, puedes usar la función parseInt() para que el resultado mostrado no contenga la parte decimal:
    var diff = parseInt(         ( (finalDatetime - realDatetime) *-1   )   )  ;
    var segundos = pad(Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60));
    var minutos = pad(Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60));
    var horas = pad(Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
    $("#tiempo").text(horas +":"+minutos+":"+segundos);
            
        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aquí un código simple que detiene un interval

```js
let someInterval = setInterval(function () { document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = Math.random() }, 500)

function clearSomeInterval() {
  clearInterval(someInterval)
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="clearSomeInterval()">clear interval</button>
```

PD: Respondiendo a "no logro que funcione"

```
...
// tu interval se llama intervalID
var intervalID =setInterval(function() {
                    tiempoTicado(finalDatetime,org,presente); 
                    }, 1000); // Llamar cada segundo

                }
                else{
                    alert("No ha entrado");
                    $switch.prop('checked', false);
                    displayButton(org);
// sin embargo estas pasando la funcion "tiempoTicado", tienes que pasar el intervalID
                   clearInterval(tiempoTicado); //No funciona
                    }
...
```

Comment: Es algo similar a lo que tengo yo hecho pero o consigo que funcione.

Comment: @LorenzoMartín agregué un pequeño análisis a tu código, revisar si este es el problema

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

**Saludos**

Debes usar **`clearInterval`** (mira en https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval) para ello el `setInterval` asignarlo a una variable y esa variable pasarla al clearInterval; desde luego ejecutarse en el momento que dseseas el Interval concluya.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN *(por comentario)***

Te comento; para que funcione la variable tiene que ser global a la página o el archivo javascript; cuida el ámbito donde la declaras. A continuación estructura:
*De forma global a la página*

```
<html>
<!-- meta y tag que necesites -->
<!-- General a la página -->
<script>
   var varInterval; // Aquí para efectos simples la declaro; más adelante la inicializamos

   function iniciandoIntervar(){
     // Inicializamos la variable
      varInterval = setInterval(/* la delcaración habitual */, /* el tiempo */)
   }

   function detenetInterval() {
      // la variable inicializada la pasamos para detener el interval
      clearInterval(varInterval);
   }


</script>
<body>
<!-- Tus elementos -->
</body>
</html>
```

*Desde un javascript*

> Tomando el código arriba pero separandolo en archivos asumiremos que el js se llama **`miInterval.js`**

*Contenido de `miInterval.js`*

```
var varInterval; // Aquí para efectos simples la declaro; más adelante la inicializamos


   function iniciandoIntervar(){
     // Inicializamos la variable
      varInterval = setInterval(/* la delcaración habitual */, /* el tiempo */)
   }

   function detenetInterval() {
      // la variable inicializada la pasamos para detener el interval
      clearInterval(varInterval);
   }
```

*La página html*

```
<html>
<!-- meta y tag que necesites -->
<!-- General a la página -->
<script src="miInterval.js" ></script>
<body>
<!-- Tus elementos -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el interés, he intentando hacerlo según dice el manual y no tengo forma. Una vez que entra en el interval, no se como pararlo. Si la segunda vez que entra en la función, no se cumple la condición de presente==1 se debe parar pero el interval sigue ejecutandose.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, lo he hecho con funciones como me ha puesto para hacerlo mas modulable pero sigo sin poder parar el interval.